# What is the correct way to create a system header only library in bazel?

Tags: c++, bazel

We are migrating a CMake project to Bazel. We have several header only libraries that are tagged SYSTEM in CMake project to suppress some warnings. When migrating these to Bazel, the way we are able to make this work is by using the below

```
cc_library(
    name = "lib",
    srcs = ["include/header1.h", ...],
    includes = ["include"],
)
```

This works but as per [Bazel C++ documentation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#hdrs), it is not recommended to have interface/public headers in `srcs`. Those should be part of `hdrs`. Adding these to headers doesn't work because it uses the regular `-I` based inclusion instead of `-isystem`.

Is our way of doing this fine, although not recommended by bazel? If not, what would be the correct way of doing it?

EDIT:
After some digging, found the `textual_hdrs` attribute on `cc_library` and using that it seems to work too. And this seems to be a cleaner approach than adding the public headers to `srcs`. Now the rule looks like this

```
cc_library(
    name = "lib",
    textual_hdrs = ["include/header1.h", ...],
    includes = ["include"],
)
```

This looks like a good solution for us, except that the documentation on textual_hdrs isn't clear enough to indicate that this is what it is meant for.

PS: It is really not possible for us to refactor the code to fix the warnings as there are numerous libraries like this and just completely outside the scope of this migration effort.

Comment: Are these third-party libraries?

Comment: Not really. The header files are part of the project.

BTW I tried introducing cc_import but it doesn't like it as these are header only libraries. Maybe I was doing something wrong?

Comment: Then it would probably be a better idea to spend time fixing warnings (and potential bugs) rather than migrating to bazel.

Comment: In an ideal world we would have loved to do that. Unfortunately right now that is not really an option. And the approach I mentioned seems to work. So would like to understand if it is a no go, and if there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: This is a legitimate question.  Rather than "just fix the code", -isystem exists for a reason and I would hope to see an answer that can actually be put to action.  My situation is very similar: large quantities of in-house _generated code_ that produces some warnings, but need to be silenced.  "Just fix the code" is not useful or remotely helpful.  Is there a technical answer?

Comment: The second _ugly_ alternative is to wrap your headers and silence the warnings with compiler specific pragmas. But I agree with VTT; if you control the code you can fix the warnings.

Comment: I don't want to be reiterating the "fix your code" but there is a bit of a conflict in the question already, because that likely is the answer to "what would be the correct way of doing it?" If for whatever reason that is not considered practical, desire for correctness must usually give way to some more or less dirty workaround to patch over it. There is a whole continuum between "The Right Thing" and "Well, it appears to work at least most of the time" and each needs to decide where they can and are willing to sit on that (and those lines should be clear in the question).

Comment: André, OndrejK. Thanks for your responses.

I understand the sentiment behind "fix your code" and I am not denying it would be the ideal approach. I had anticipated that and hence the original question's PS section mentioned it not really being an option. The code residing in the project just gives the migration team nominal "control" over it. The developers don't want to fix the warnings right now, especially because CMake has option to handle it. May be I should re-phrase the question to say "what is better way" rather than correct way? (although that sounds weird to my ears)

Comment: @André the pragma way seems more doable than fixing warnings as of now, although even that would probably need us to touch a lot of files. It would be nice to have a bazel way of doing this, i.e. via some bazel options.

What would be really nice to know is whether the approach that I have given has any red flags. Because it seems to work. I even checked incrementality and caching behavior, albeit on a toy example, and that seems to match the bazel recommended way

Answer (score 4):

It turns out adding it to `hdrs` **does** work if you make sure that strip_include_prefix is None (or not passed). We had a macro that was wrapping up the cc_library instance and it was defaulting strip_include_prefix to empty string. Interestingly this doesn't affect `textual_hdrs` or `srcs`, but does affect `hdrs`

In summary the below seems to work fine

```
cc_library(
    name = "lib",
    hdrs = ["include/header1.h", ...],
    includes = ["include"],
)
```